# How to get grade average and do a search method?

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I have been working on this project for days now and I got most of it down however there are three problems that I am having. I am trying to calculate the average grade from a ifstream file, the program reads it successfully however when I pass the array from one function to another, it just displays 0 and F as I am trying to display the percentage and letter grade.

My second question is how do I get the array to only print out elements that are populated. So if I create an array of 10 and only populate the first three elements, how would I got to only get those first three elements to print only?

And my other question is when I try doing a search, it keeps saying record not found even I typed the name correctly. The record is being search by last name.

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void greeting(string[], string[], double[], double[], double[], int);
int getinfo(string[], string[], double[], double[], double[], int);
int calculateaverageandgrade(string[], string[], double[], double[], double [], int);
void sortandsearch(string[], string[], double[], double[], double[], int);
void goodbye(string[], string[], double[], double[], double[]);

int main() {

string fname[10] = { "" };
string lname[10] = { "" };
double grade[10] = { 0 };
double grade2[10] = { 0 };
double grade3[10] = { 0 };
const int arraysize = 10;


greeting(fname, lname, grade, grade2, grade3, arraysize);
getinfo(fname, lname, grade, grade2, grade3, arraysize);
calculateaverageandgrade(fname, lname, grade, grade2, grade3, arraysize);



system("pause");
return 0;
}


void greeting(string fname[], string lname[], double grade[], double grade2    [], double grade3[], int arraysize) {

int choice = int();
char cont = 'y';

while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y')
{

    cout << setw(60) << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << setw(66) << "======================" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tToday we will be calculating grades from a file" << endl << "\t\t\t\tthat you can provide for us using notepad." << endl <<  "\t\t\t\tBe sure to update your file every time you run the program" << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(64) << "Reading file...." << endl;
    cout << setw(66) << "======================" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(65) << "1. Calculate Grades." << endl;
    cout << setw(63) << "2. Search Grades" << endl;
    cout << setw(68) << "2. Exit from the Program." << endl;

    cout << endl;

    cout << setw(70) << "Please Enter your Selection: ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Invalid selection" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    }
    else
    {
        if (choice == 1)
        {
        calculateaverageandgrade(fname, lname, grade, grade2, grade3, arraysize);
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            sortandsearch(fname, lname, grade, grade2, grade3, arraysize);
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            goodbye(fname, lname, grade, grade2, grade3);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Selection!" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)....";

    cin >> cont;
}

}





int getinfo(string fname[], string lname[],double grade[], double grade2[], double grade3[], int arraysize) {


system("cls");
ifstream in;
in.open("data.txt");

int i = 0;


while (!in.eof()) {

    in >> fname[i] >> lname[i] >> grade[i] >> grade2[i] >> grade3 [i];
    ++i;
}

arraysize = i;
return arraysize;


}

int calculateaverageandgrade(string fname[], string lname[], double grade[], double grade2[], double grade3[], int arraysize) {

system("cls");
const int i = 10;

double total[i];

for (int a = 0; a < arraysize; ++a) {

    cout << "Name:" << setw(20) << "Score: " << setw(20) << "Grade: " << endl;;
    cout << fname[a] << " " << lname[a];
    total[a] = grade[a] + grade2[a] + grade3[a];
    total[a] = total[a] / 3;
    cout << setw(20) << total[a] << endl;

    if (total[a] >= 90) {
        cout << setw(40) << "A" << endl;
    }
    else if (total[a] >= 80) {
        cout << setw(41) << "B" << endl;
    }
    else if(total[a] >= 70) {
        cout << setw(41) << "C" << endl;
    }
    else if (total[a] >= 60) {
        cout << setw(41) << "D" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << setw(41) << "F" << endl;
    }


}


system("pause");
return total[i];
}

void sortandsearch(string fname[], string lname[], double grade[], double grade2[], double grade3[], int arraysize) {

    system("cls");
    string nameSearch = string();
    int i = int();
    bool flag = false;
    char key = char();

    system("cls");
    cout << "\nEnter Name to be Searched: ";
    cin >> nameSearch;

    while (i<arraysize)
    {
        if (lname[i] == nameSearch)
        {
            cout << "Record Found --- ";
            cout << "Record # " << i + 1 << " contains " << nameSearch << "'s information." << endl;
            flag = true;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    if (flag == false)
    {
        cout << "\nRecord Not Found!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\nPress any Key to Continue...";
    key = _getch();
}



void goodbye(string fname[], string lname[], double grade[], double grade2[], double grade3[]) {

system("cls");
cout << setw(70) << "Thanks for using my program!" << endl;
system("pause");
exit(1);

}
```

Comment: I forgot to put comments on my code! If you guys need me to update for readability I can do that.

Comment: **One** question per question, please. Avoid asking more than one question in post, on SO. *Especially* if they are only loosely related.

Comment: `int choice = int();` What ?

Comment: Okay sorry about the multiple questions, I am fairly new here as I really do not use this platform as I only ask questions in which I am seriously lost in.